# Can we run a particular Redis Query using Jmeter?

Tags: javascript, redis, key, jmeter, beanshell

I want to retrieve particular key values from Redis, using jmeter. I am fairly new to both jmeter and redis. For your instance

I want to connect to the host, 
then retrieve value for "get batchid_dasd8adasda8asda0"and
then use the result in my beanshell preprocessor.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMeter to send HTTP, JDBC, SOAP and many other type of requests.

JMeter does not have built-in support for testing Redis but you can use [Redis Data Set Plugin](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RedisDataSet/) in JMeter to test your scenario.

Since you are new to JMeter, therefore I will first recommend to you learn basic usage of JMeter. You can start from testing something simpler (HTTP or JDBC) whichever you are comfortable with and once you are clear on that you can move on to using Redis plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by installing the Webdis HTTP interface for Redis - either building it from the source [Github repository](https://github.com/nicolasff/webdis) or installing the ready-to-use [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/anapsix/webdis/).

Since all testing should be done within a sandboxed environment this should not be a blocker when it comes down to security.  Once you have it installed, you can use the HTTP sampler to send any kind of command to the underlying Redis store.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JMeter file and bean shell script to fetch a set of keys from redis and put them into variables used by a looping HTTP GET request.

https://bitbucket.org/barryknapp/shared/src/d62f8ebb57ede1d15a3bd7683adfdd02cd039369/jmeter/?at=master